# have issue passing data in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Having trouble in passing data in this reactjs, I am new to react js, the error shows

Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {sku, inventoryCount}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Batches`.

```
export default class Batches extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Example AJAX call
    ajax('/mft/api/reports/view', {
      success: data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data[1]);
        this.setState({data: data.data});
      }
    });
  }


 render() {
    return <div className="content">
      <Heading>Batches</Heading>
      <div>{this.state.data}</div>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: show your `render` method in `Batches`

Comment: add render method please

Comment: what is `typeof data.data`? If it is an array of objects, then use a map function to generate the `Batch` items. Make sure you assign a `key` to each of the `Batch` item!

Comment: added already..